# How to disable new user registration using identity Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1. I need to temporary prevent new user from signing up.

How can I do that?

I tried looking at the options when registering the service but don't see an option to allow me to disable registration.

```
services.AddIdentity(options => 
{

});
```

Comment: does hiding the form or a condition in register service not work for you?

Comment: no. I need to completely block any register request.

Comment: are you using `Identity`'s ui or you have implemented it yourself

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filter to block requests to the register page. This example filter redirects the request to the root path, but you could redirect to a page informing the user about the disabled registration. This way you are only adding an attribute without changing any registration code.

*BlockFilter.cs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System;

namespace MySite.Filters
{
    public class BlockFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {

        public BlockFilter()
        {
        }
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

            context.Result = new RedirectResult("/"); //Redirect to you desired page

        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class BlockAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public BlockAttribute() : base(typeof(BlockFilter))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new BlockAttribute());
    });

    services.AddRazorPages();
```

*Register.cshtml.cs*

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Block]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems no such an option to disable registration. But you can make some changes manually.

You can first scaffold two identity pages: `Account\Register,` `Account\Login`.

Edit Register.cshtml.cs. Redirect users to the login page if they land on the Registration page.

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return RedirectToPage("Login");
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        return RedirectToPage("Login");
    }
}
```

Edit Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml to look like the following.

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Go to Login";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
</li>
```

Remove the registration link from Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml

```
@*
<p>
    <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
</p>
*@
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this information might be a bit dated, it could still be valuable.

Restricting access to user registration in ASP.NET Core Identity can be achieved by following the steps below:

Navigate to the "ProjectPath\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Register.cshtml" file.

Add a conditional statement to restrict access exclusively to authenticated users. Otherwise, display a validation message.

```
@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>Registration is restricted to logged in users.</p>
}
else
{
    //Registration form content here
}
```

Next, in the "ProjectPath\Pages\Shared_LoginPartial.cshtml" view, relocate the 'Register' link within the authenticated code block. This step will ensure that the link is hidden from unauthenticated users

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity?.Name!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post" >
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
```